# Ошибка в RoR при использовании Bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Здравствуйте, учу RoR по [ruby tut](http://railstutorial.ru/chapters/4_0/filling-in-the-layout#sec-custom_css) и, дойдя до листинга 5.5, у меня выбрасывает ошибку (все файлы заполнены соответсвенно туториалу, ошибка кидает при импорте лиситнга 5.5):

```
NoMethodError in StaticPages#home    
Showing /home/sych/rails_projects/sample_app/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #5 raised:

    undefined method `environment' for nil:NilClass
      (in /home/sych/rails_projects/sample_app/app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss)
```

Подскажите, в чём может быть проблема и как её исправить? Все файлы заполнены согласно туториалу.

Comment: В Gemfile выставлены те же версии гемов, что и в книге?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще-то процедура подключения бутстрапа ясно описана на https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass

1. Добавить гем в `Gemfile`.

   ```
   gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.5'
   gem 'sass-rails', '>= 3.2'
   ```
2. Подключить css. Добавить в application.css.scss следующее. Если есть только application.css, то переименовать его в .css.scss. Оставлять оба — плохо.

   ```
   @import "bootstrap-sprockets";
   @import "bootstrap";
   ```
3. В application.js подключить скрипты

   ```
   //= require jquery
   //= require bootstrap
   ```

Предыдущий отвечающий забыл `;` при подключении стилей.

Comment: Добавлять @import в .css не имеет смысла, так как это работает только в .scss.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй следующее. В `assets/stylesheets/application.css.sass` добавь

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets"

@import "bootstrap"
```

Затем в `assets/javascripts/application.js` добавь

```
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
```

Comment: Cпасибо за ответ, но не помогло
application.css.sass не было  в директории, был только application.css. Я попробовал и туда добавить, затем создал application.css.sass, сделал тоже самое, увы

Comment: application.css надо просто переименовать в application.css.sass

Comment: Сделал так, появилась новая ошибка: Sass::SyntaxError in StaticPages#home

Comment: Эврика, работает, теперь ошибка синтаксиса Sass, как тебе уже советовали в вк, залей проект на github, чтобы точнее можно было понять, что не так.

Answer (score 0):

При подключении `gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.5'` не стартует WEBrick, ибо весь тьюториал основан на версии Rails 4.0.2, а упомянутый выше бутсрап тянет и другую версию рейлз, что делает геморройным дальнейшее изучение Rails по данному тьюториалу.

> /home/maxie/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@hartl/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.6/lib/bootstrap-sass/engine.rb:11:in `block in ': uninitialized constant Sprockets::Rails::VERSION (NameError) ....

и так далее

Решил проблему!!! И решение простое, до безобразия.
1) В Gemfile находим строку **gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'** и 
   меняем ее на **gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.3'**
2) bundle update
3) bundle install
И все работает. И не нужно удалять application.css.scss или переименовывать его.
Решение нашел [здесь](http://pr8x.com/st/questions/25594215/railstutorial-error-after-adding-import-bootstrap.html)  - Answer 4. Только не надо удалять Gemfile.lock работает и так. И что самое главное - bootstrap не игнорируется как предлагали другие, он подключается и работает

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогло с забугорного стаковерфлоу.

gem 'sprockets', '2.11.0'
в Gemfile 
и
bundle update

Может потребуется удалить Gemfile.lock

Суть в том что гем был обновлем сам до более новой версии и начались траблы. А в гемфайл не была указана версия данного модуля с указанием точной версии.